# how to get element id from custom required function when using jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.validate to check my form for errors and I am trying to get the id of the element that has raised an error.

Here is my basic working code, hopefully it should be clear from this what I am after:

```
function customError(){
    alert("this is where I want the element ID");
}


function submitForm($form){
    $form.validate({
       required: customError(),
       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
       submitHandler: function(){
           alert("submited");
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ... 
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      customError(element.attr('id'));
    },
   ...
```

Comment: serious blushes for this one. That will teach me for coding way to early after little sleep.